# Table position text

Tags: tables, spacing, positioning, line

I want to insert several tables into my text, so that they are in the middle of the page, centrally under the text. this works for the smaller tables, but for example with this one, the table starts at the height of the text and then goes over the edge on the right. How can I make it stay in the middle and have the same amount of space on both sides?
At the end a picture as it looks in the PDF

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|| c | c | c | c | c ||}
 \hline 
 %\multicolumn{5}{|| c ||}{\Glsxtrshort{mos}-Durchschnitt mit Standardabweichung}\\
 %\hline 
 & Links & Rechts & Vorwärts & Rückwärts \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|| l ||}{\Glsxtrshort{mos}-\glsxtrshort{ap} [mm]}\\
 \hline
 \Gls{perturbation} 1-10 & -169.68 $\pm$ 69.51 & 103.07 $\pm$ 106.11 & 16.72 $\pm$ 78.36 & 16.02 $\pm$ 77.39 \\
 \hline
 \Gls{perturbation} 11-20 & -188.40 $\pm$ 156.5 & 94.6 $\pm$ 114.08 & 22.49 $\pm$ 79.89 & 27.46 $\pm$ 64.23 \\
 \hline
 \Gls{perturbation} 21-30 & -151.19 $\pm$ 54.76 & 85.91 $\pm$ 106.06 & 19.69 $\pm$ 77.13 & 31.41 $\pm$ 61.33 \\
 \hline
 \Gls{perturbation} 31-40 & -184.55 $\pm$ 102.53 & 126.66 $\pm$ 95.82 & 23.63 $\pm$ 84.58 & 23.03 $\pm$ 76.34 \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|| l ||}{\Glsxtrshort{mos}-\glsxtrshort{ml} [mm]}\\
 \hline
 \Gls{perturbation} 1-10 & 43.53 $\pm$ 32.76 & 49.8 $\pm$ 35.61 & 53.69 $\pm$ 57.92 & 51.25 $\pm$ 50.98 \\
 \hline
 \Gls{perturbation} 11-20 & 53.63 $\pm$ 44.09 & 41.36 $\pm$ 46.47 & 49.02 $\pm$ 48.18 & 52.74 $\pm$ 44.53 \\
 \hline
 \Gls{perturbation} 21-30 & 49.84 $\pm$ 49.67 & 34.05 $\pm$ 45.55 & 44.15 $\pm$ 57.51 & 47.45 $\pm$ 49.59 \\
 \hline
 \Gls{perturbation} 31-40 & 31.2 $\pm$ 51.35 & 44.94 $\pm$ 30.85 & 54.57 $\pm$ 62.89 & 49.31 $\pm$ 53.05 \\
 \hline
\caption{\Glsxtrshort{mos}-Durchschnittswerte des Trainings mit Standardabweichung}
\label{tab:mittelwerteTraining}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

[image: Table in wrong position]

Comment: don't put longtable in a center environment (it does not center it) for the width see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: can't you put `perturbation` in column1 heading and not repeat on every line, then the table would fit

Comment: Why you cannot put the table into the `table` environment, in that way can you use the position controls (like `ht`) and the `centering` control instead of the `center` environment?

Comment: @FaustoMauricioLagosSuárez because I am not finished with my work and theres the possibility a table is about two pages and bsides of that I have the same problem with images